# Facebook Like box - Being able to like the current page using dynamic URL

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, facebook-like

I am new to Facebook and I am trying to add the Facebook like button to my website. From the developer section of Facebook, I got the following code to add the like button:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http://www.mysite.com&width=292&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&stream=false&header=false&height=62" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Now I want to be able to place the like button on each page of my website. For this reason, I think using a static link in the above code will be useless. Hence I have my own function that populates the current page URL (including any variables that might be present in the URL) in a constant called: **CURRENT_URL**

So my revised code for the Like button looks like below:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=<?php echo CURRENT_URL; ?>&width=292&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&stream=false&header=false&height=62" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:292px; height:62px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

When I use the above revised code in my website, I dont see the Like box. Instead, I see an error page in the Iframe that says:

```
The page you requested was not found.
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.
```

If I do a general `<?php echo CURRENT_URL; ?`, it is showing the correct URL. There is no problem with the value of the constant. This makes me feel that the iframe is simply trying to load the website name without parsing the constant value. I just want a code that I can use throughout the website without having to manually change the Like button value for each of the pages of my website.

So my question is:

**How can I make this iframe detect the current page URL (including any variables that I may be passing via the URL) and populate the Like button URL value to the current page URL so that user can like this page.**

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE (Solution):**

I found out that theres a big confusion about all this. There are actually 2 types of Like features. One is a normal Like button and the other is Like box. Here are the links:

**Like Button:**
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

**Like Box:**
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

Use the Like **Button** code if you want to be people to like the individual pages of your website. The Like **Box** asks you for: Facebook Page URL. This means that you CANNOT use it for your users to Like your web pages. (I am still working on understanding about Facebook Page URL and how it works and when it fails)

Hope this information helps anyone else going through the same trouble and confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just echo the like button and you won't have this problems - something like that:

```
function likeButton($url_to_like, $action = "like") {
    return sprintf('<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="%s" show_faces="true" width="450" action="%s"></fb:like>',
$url_to_like, $action);
}
```

I'm using the javascript version, but it's the same with the iframe :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I updated my posting with the possible solution. I was using code for Like Box when in fact I should be using code for Like button. Your code was a pointer towards my solution. Hence I am choosing your answer as my solution as well. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: BTW, do you know what the Facebook Page URL is and how to use it? I tried to visit www.facebook.com/mycompany and it returned a 404 error. This means that my page is not being found although I have created it. Does the business page need any activiation? I am very new to this and do not know (yet) how to proceed with it. Would appreciate any more input you may have. Thanks.

Comment: I think facebook pages have some random ID after the page name
(i.e - http://www.facebook.com/pages/WTF-Test-Page/142187565841842 )
Check the link after you created your page :)

Comment: Wow, this is so confusing! You are correct about the link. But I am unable understand the operational difference between Like Button and Like Box. Both seem to be doing the same thing (as per my understanding so far and I am a newbie to Facebook and its integration). Reading the Help section on Facebook has not helped me much as its the same technical jargon revolving around. Can you please tell me what the difference is and when to use them in a non-technical way, if you know it? Thanks.

Comment: The Like button is for universal purposes - you can like everything and place it everywhere. (i.e like a blog post or article)
On the other side:
The Like Box is for facebook pages(which is something like public account, i'm not sure about the definition). It shows how many users have liked the given page, the wall (called stream) of the page PLUS a Like Button for the given page.
Thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the function is a great idea. We have the same issue on our site take a look at it here ([TAPNET Online Backup](http://www.tapnet.biz)) because we use a common code snippet for all pages on our right side bar. I tried removing the value in `href=""` and it must be pulling the current URL because it is working.  I see the same `#`'s as were there before and when I like any of the pages that weren't liked before the number increments as expected. Try that.